# command handler only recognize the top-most folder instead of all the folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i have a problem, my Command Handler only recognize the top Folder inside my Commands Directory. Its supposed to show all of the available Folder in Commands Directory but it only showed the 'test' category which is the top one. any help would be really appreciated.

**Folder/Directory Construction:**

[image: My Folder/Directory Construction]

**console.log output:**

[image: console.log Output]

**Command Handler Code:**

```
const {readdirSync} = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading('Category', 'Command', ' Load status');
var logged = false;
const path = require('node:path')

module.exports = (client) => {
readdirSync('./Commands/').forEach(dir => {
    var commands = readdirSync(`./Commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(let file of commands){
        let pull = require(`../Commands/${dir}/${file}`);
        if(pull.name){
            client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
            table.addRow(dir,file,'✔️   -> Command Loaded')
        } else {
            table.addRow(dir,file,'❌   -> Command Error')
            continue;
        }
        if(pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))       
    }
    if(!logged) {
        console.log(table.toString())
        console.log(`[Command] Command Handler is Ready! | Total Commands: ${commands.length}`)
        logged = true
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are overwriting the commands variable after each folder has been looped through. Try this:

```
const {readdirSync} = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading('Category', 'Command', ' Load status');
var logged = false;
const path = require('node:path')

module.exports = (client) => {
readdirSync('./Commands/').forEach(dir => {

    var commands = []
    commands.push(readdirSync(`./Commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')));

    for(let file of commands){
        let pull = require(`../Commands/${dir}/${file}`);
        if(pull.name){
            client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
            table.addRow(dir,file,'✔️   -> Command Loaded')
        } else {
            table.addRow(dir,file,'❌   -> Command Error')
            continue;
        }
        if(pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))       
    }
    if(!logged) {
        console.log(table.toString())
        console.log(`[Command] Command Handler is Ready! | Total Commands: ${commands.length}`)
        logged = true
    }
});
}
```

If this doesn't help than it might still be that issue I referred to above but the edits I made might not be compatible with your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i've figured it out, i just put the 'if(!logged)' outside the readdirSync scope.